# How to manage a framework that's depend on network call and database queries?

Tags: ios, cocoa, frameworks

I have a project that needs to implement a framework potentially be shared with many other projects, this framework is about "subscription".

Basically what this one do is wraps `StoreKit` in iOS and talks to our server as well, then potentially save something in the database. I do have a database stack and networking stack in the project but I have not abstract them out into a framework/library yet.

So my question is, I am not very sure about the correct way of achieving this. Should I make my database stack and network stack as 2 separate frameworks first? then create the "subscription" framework by having them in it? But I also found this is called `umbrella framework` which is not recommended.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, there's no "correct" way. It depends on how flexible you want this to be and how much work you want to do. IMHO there are, basically, two choice: (a/lazy) create a single framework with all of the resources it needs imbedded/compiled inside the framework. (b/eager) create N frameworks, one for each major, encapsulated, service. The high-level frameworks will simply link to the low-level frameworks. Each project will imbed all N frameworks.

Comment: @JamesBucanek thanks for that, could you post as a answer and I will accept that, maybe a bit more details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there are two ways to engineer this.

Option A / lazy

Build all of your reusable classes into a single framework. That framework would include/compile all of the supporting code it needs (database, networking, ...) to do its job.

Then share that reusable framework amongst your various app project. Remember to not only to link to the framework, but also embed it in your app.

This is the simplest to set up, design, and maintain (for a single person). However, it also means creating a monolithic library that might be overly broad and/or hide too much of the underlaying technologies.

Option B / enthusiastic

Build each of your reusable components into its own framework. The high-level frameworks would link to (but not embed) the low-level frameworks.

Your app projects would then both link to and embed all of the frameworks it needs.

At run time, each framework will (should) magically load itself as needed.

This is a lot more work, but has a few advantages. Each major service has its own I/F so your app can directly use the components without having to "drill through" the high-level frameworks that define your custom service.

It also might mean you have more flexibility in what code you include. One app might use client registration services, the database, and a server connection, while a second app might just use client lockup and the server.

It might also make maintenance (particularly if different engineers are responsible  for each services) and regression testing easier.

Finally, there are no right answers here, just tradeoffs.